# Unit testing when mocking file upload in php

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

I am just stuck at this point.

I am mocking a Filesystem class, which has the method dumpFile, which uses file_put_contents under the hood.

Since it's mocked, the file will never be uploaded. That's why my function which tries to open the file fails.

How do I solve this problem?

Here is the method to be tested

```
try {
            $this->filesystem->dumpFile($filePath, $decodedData);
        } catch (IOExceptionInterface $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
            throw new UserError('File could not be written');
        }

        $mimeType = Base64FileUtil::getMimeType($decodedData);

        return [
            [
                'name' =>  'name',
                'contents' => $filename
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'file',
                'contents' => Psr7\Utils::tryFopen($filePath, 'r'),
                'headers'  => [
                    'content-type' => $mimeType
                ],
            ],
            [
                'name' => 'dir',
                'contents' => $input->dir
            ]
        ];
```

here is the unit test

```
public function testUploadFileSuccessfully(): void
    {
        $input = new FileUpoadInput(
            '123abc',
            'foo',
            'loremipsum.png',
            base64_encode($this->fileContents)
        );

        $this->filesystem
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('dumpFile')
            ->with(
                $this->stringEndsWith('loremipsum.png'),
                $this->equalTo(base64_decode($input->content, true))
            );

     $this->fileRepo->uploadFile($input);
    }
```